# Is there a SEDE query to find number of up votes received?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I am interested how many up votes I, and other people, have received. Is this possible to find out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/353753?UserId=252153) will give you that number:

```sql
select count(*) as [number of upvotes]
from votes v 
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
where v.votetypeid =2 -- upmod
and p.owneruserid = ##userid:int## -- 252153
```

You have received 1034 upvotes on this site, per the post date.

The [votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) table hold for every post the different votetypes. Up votes (called Upmod for some reason) are recorded with votetypeid = 2. By joining the votes and post table you'll find the upvotes on your posts.